# ReactJS - How to fix compile error in a chat app?

Tags: reactjs

After compiling I receive this error message:

> Failed to compile src\App.js   Line 4:1:  'state' is not defined
> no-undef

Code App.js:

```
import Messages from "./Messages";
import Input from "./Input"
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const initialState = {
  messages: [
    {
      text: "This is a test message!",
      member: {
        color: "blue",
        username: "bluemoon"
      }
    }
  ],
  member: {
    username: randomName(),
    color: randomColor()
  }
}

function randomName() {
  const adjectives = ["autumn", "hidden", "bitter", "misty", "silent", "empty", "dry", "dark", "summer", "icy", "delicate", "quiet", "white", "cool", "spring", "winter", "patient", "twilight", "dawn", "crimson", "wispy", "weathered", "blue", "billowing", "broken", "cold", "damp", "falling", "frosty", "green", "long", "late", "lingering", "bold", "little", "morning", "muddy", "old", "red", "rough", "still", "small", "sparkling", "throbbing", "shy", "wandering", "withered", "wild", "black", "young", "holy", "solitary", "fragrant", "aged", "snowy", "proud", "floral", "restless", "divine", "polished", "ancient", "purple", "lively", "nameless"];
  const nouns = ["waterfall", "river", "breeze", "moon", "rain", "wind", "sea", "morning", "snow", "lake", "sunset", "pine", "shadow", "leaf", "dawn", "glitter", "forest", "hill", "cloud", "meadow", "sun", "glade", "bird", "brook", "butterfly", "bush", "dew", "dust", "field", "fire", "flower", "firefly", "feather", "grass", "haze", "mountain", "night", "pond", "darkness", "snowflake", "silence", "sound", "sky", "shape", "surf", "thunder", "violet", "water", "wildflower", "wave", "water", "resonance", "sun", "wood", "dream", "cherry", "tree", "fog", "frost", "voice", "paper", "frog", "smoke", "star"];
  const adjective = adjectives[Math.floor(Math.random() * adjectives.length)];
  const noun = nouns[Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length)];
  return adjective + noun;
};

function randomColor() {
  return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
};

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  
  const onSendMessage = message => { 
    const messages = state.messages
    messages.push({
      text: message,
      member: state.member
    })
    this.setState({messages: messages})
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h1>My Chat App</h1>
      </div>
      <Messages
        messages={state.messages}
        currentMember={state.member}
      />
      <Input
        onSendMessage={onSendMessage}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code Messages.js:

```
import {Component} from "react";
import React from "react";
    
import {Component} from "react";
import React from "react";

class Messages extends Component {
  renderMessage(message, index) {
    const { member, text } = message;
    const { currentMember } = this.props;
    const messageFromMe = member.id === currentMember.id;
    const className = messageFromMe
      ? "Messages-message currentMember"
      : "Messages-message";
    return (
      <li key={index} className={className}>
        <span className="avatar" style={{ backgroundColor: member.color }} />
        <div className="Message-content">
          <div className="username">{member.username}</div>
          <div className="text">{text}</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { messages } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul className="Messages-list">
        {messages.map((m, index) => this.renderMessage(m, index))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

Code Input.js

```
import {Component} from "react";
import React from "react";

class Input extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({text: ""});
    this.props.onSendMessage?.(this.state.text);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Input">
        <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
          <input
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
            value={this.state.text}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your message and press ENTER"
            autofocus="true"
          />
          <button>Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Input;
```

It's a simple project, but I'm new to programing and I would appreciate your help. I have added the component Messages so we can fast find the solution. I think that adding the CSS is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Functional components don't have a defined `this`, and any state should be declared in a `useState` hook.

## Solution

Use the `useState` hook and set initial state.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const initialState = {
  messages: [
    {
      text: "This is a test message!",
      member: {
        color: "blue",
        username: "bluemoon"
      }
    }
  ],
  member: {
    username: randomName(),
    color: randomColor()
  }
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Messages
        messages={state.messages}
        currentMember={state.member}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For the "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" error(s)

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
> onSendMessage
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Algebra materijali/Test2/chat-app/src/App.js:43
>   40 |     text: message,
>   41 |     member: state.member
>   42 |   })
> > 43 |   this.setState({messages: messages})
>      | ^  44 | }
>   45 | 
>   46 | return (
> View compiled
> Input.onSubmit
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/Algebra materijali/Test2/chat-app/src/Input.js:16
>   13 | onSubmit(e) {
>   14 |   e.preventDefault();
>   15 |   this.setState({text: ""});
> > 16 |   this.props.onSendMessage?.(this.state.text);
>      | ^  17 | }
>   18 | 
>   19 | render() {
> ```

Bind `this` to `onChange` and `onSubmit` in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    text: ""
  }

  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

or convert `onChange` and `onSubmit` to arrow functions to have `this` bound to them automatically.

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({text: e.target.value});
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({text: ""});
  this.props.onSendMessage(this.state.text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it still won't work. Failed to compile
src\App.js  Line 5:1:    'initialState' is not defined  no-undef Line 34:38:  'initialState' is not defined  no-undef I'm confused.

Comment: Now I have have whole bunch of Errors. Maybe I should give you the code for both components, so we can find the source of the problem.

Comment: @AuxRenard The `state.messages` array objects don't have the `color` and `username` properties nested in a `clientData ` property, they are at the root, i.e. `member.color` and `member.username`. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-how-to-fix-compile-error-in-a-chat-app-nexlp). Can you better clarify what a "whole bunch of errors" means?

Comment: @ Drew Reese Omg, you were right, it works. Thank you so much, I think I can figure out the rest. You are a magician, I can't thank you enough, you saved me.

Comment: @ Drew Reese Can I bother you for one more thing. function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  
  onSendMessage = (message) => {
    const messages = this.state.messages
    messages.push({
      text: message,
      member: this.state.member
    })
    this.setState({messages: messages})
  }             Failed to compile
src\App.js
  Line 39:3:  'onSendMessage' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @AuxRenard Declare the `onSendMessage` variable, i.e. `const onSendMessage = message => { .... }`. Also, don't forget to remove/fix the `this` references, there is no `this` in functional components.

Comment: @ Drew Reese It never ends, sorry. Check the code for the Input in the question. If you solve it I owe you a beer.

Comment: Whatever is rendering that `Input` component should pass an `onSendMessage` prop. You can conditionally guard (Optional Chaining Operator) this call if `onSendMessage` is expected to sometimes be undefined, `this.props.onSendMessage?.(this.state.text);`.

Comment: @ Drew Reese I promise this is last issue. I don't want to waste more of your time, but I'm really bad at this. After submitting the message i get a error. I updated the code is that OK?

Comment: @ Drew Reese When I type the message this pops up: https://pastebin.com/FagiCuvG

Comment: @AuxRenard In `Input` component, either bing `this` to `onChange` and `onSubmit` in the `constructor`, or convert them to arrow functions so `this` is bound automagically.

Comment: Something like: class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    }

    this.onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({text: ""});
    this.props.onSendMessage?.(this.state.text);
  }
  }

  state = {
    text: ""
  }